can java8 compiled code using springboot 2.7.18 run on java 17 runtime
I have my application which is compiled on java8 using springboot 2.7.18.
I need to change its runtime to java17 but when i run it it gives me below error :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

As per spring docs 2.7.18 should run on java17.
Is there any other solution apart from upgrading to springboot 3.x.

There is nothing preventing it to run in 17 or newer. So if you get this error this is due to something you yourself do in your build.

Thanks, eventually I was able to figure out the issue. Issue wasn't in spring or java environments rather it was with the docker container.  running the container with --privileged=true option it succeeded fine.
docker run --privileged=true -i -t -p 9043:9043 xyz12345098s /bin/bash
